# Ferrofluids and normal-field instability

Tags: magnetic-fields, nanoscience

Could someone explain whether the spikes and uneven surfaces you see in ferrofluids being attracted or repelled away away from (against gravity) the surface of ferrofluids would happen if the fields were reversed?

From what I can gather, the spikes are caused by gravity and surface tension acting AGAINST the magnetic field. So if the magnetic fields acted in tandem with gravity, should the surface of the liquid remain flat?

Comment: These systems try to minimize their total energy. Since the magnetic field energy density is high at the surface, the system probably tries to lower it by increasing the surface area, so the field may cause a negative surface tension... and that's probably the largest foam-hand I want to wave today. Looking forward to a real explanation, though!